# Outlook add-in in calendar meetings

Tags: outlook, add-in

I'm looking for documentation how to write add-in for the calendar meeting.
Same as "Add a Zoom Meetings" I would like to show the buttons only when its meeting or appointment (Not in Inbox like the basic tutorial)

[image]